# How to add a profile photo Smart twenty seconds template?

Tags: templates, cv

I have just started to use Latex and I'm using its templates to create my CV. My problem is that I'm not able to add the profile photo to this template. I have seen that there's a similar one with Alice example but in that one there's no the bublle diagram. Can anyone help me?Thanks a lot from a beginner :)

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please show us what code you have so far.

Comment: LaTeX does not come with templates. Template are provided by other platforms. We need to see a link to the template.

Answer (score 2):

I have only seen one "Smart Twenty Seconds" CV example online and it didn't have an image in it.  You can see a similar example of a slightly different CV at this location:

https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/smart-fancy-cv

This one does have an image.

To include an image into a LaTeX file you will have to use one of a selection of commands to include the graphics.

If you go to the link above you will see the final typeset example but on the right you will see a brown button which will take you to the source code.

In that code listing, if you look for a command `\begin{aside}` that tells LaTeX that all the subsequent commands until the `\end{aside}` command are to be treated as an "aside" which simply means some material that is related to the document but not directly part of it.  In this case the person who created the template used the "aside" literally as the material on the left side!

Immediately after the `\begin{aside}` declaration, you will find an 
`\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{img/snow_circle.png}`
statement.

This is where the person's self portrait is inserted - it has been scaled down to 18% of the original size of the image - and you can use your own scaling mechanisms such as `[width=\linewidth]` for example or `[width=\textwidth]` which do slightly different things.

This template also has Bubble Diagrams.

However, before I close, a couple of words of advice.

In this forum, you really must try and include what is known as a "Minimum Working Example" (MWE) - making general comments about particular LaTeX CV templates is not helpful.  You need to take the time and trouble to submit a sample of some actual LaTeX that you have tried to use.

The second bit of advice, and I mean this in the kindest way possible, because I have worked with LaTeX since about 1994 on and off and I still struggle with it at times.  If you expect to find "canned examples" and just get a quick fix you will die an 'orrible death!  (Said with a big smile not in a nasty manner!).  LaTeX is a programming language and must be viewed as such - it is extremely rare that something from a template will work immediately - unless you already have a lot of experience.

This being said, LaTeX (and TeX) on which it is built is one of the most beautiful and useful packages I've ever come across in 30+ years as an engineer scientist - and so if you work hard at it it will become your friend, but like any genuine friendship, it will take (literally) years and be VERY hard work and even painful at times!!!

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment, unless you can provide a means to insert an image on the requested template.

Comment: Welcome, answers should in general have an MWE is well, which is kinda impossible for template questions. The part on LaTeX itself is just off-topic, and the stuff with the email is not suited for this site.